# No GoRouter found in context 'package:go_router/src/router.dart': Failed assertion: line 489 pos 12: 'inherited != null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

After initialising firebase, in my main.dart file, I wanted users to be redirected to dashboard if they are authenticated, if not, they should be onboarded. But I keep getting the error above. This is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/src/authentication/authenticationview.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/src/authentication/controller/authentication_controller.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/src/clientdashboard/client_dashboard.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/src/onboardingscreen/onboardpages/secondpage.dart';
import 'package:flymedia_app/utils/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

import 'route/route.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const ProviderScope(
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authenticationState = ref.watch(authProvider);

    Widget getHome() {
      if (authenticationState.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated) {
        return const ClientDashBoard();
      } else if (authenticationState.status ==
          AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated) {
        return const SecondOnboard();
      } else {
        return const SecondOnboard();
      }
    }

    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 780),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (context, child) => Theme(
        data: lightTheme,
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          builder: (context, child) => getHome(),
          routerConfig: router,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'FlyMedia',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My router looks like this

```
final GoRouter router =
    GoRouter(debugLogDiagnostics: debugLogDiagnostics, routes: [

  GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
      name: 'splash'),
]);
```

I've been stuck here for a while. If I now change the SecondOnBoard to AuthenticationView, when you click on the input field I get this "

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ==================

The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
No Overlay widget found.

EditableText widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor within the closest 
LookupBoundary.
An overlay lets widgets float on top of other widget children.

To introduce an Overlay widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget 
that contains an Overlay itself, such as a Navigator, WidgetApp, MaterialApp, or 
CupertinoApp."
```

Please how can I rectify this? Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you tried to access the GoRouter instance from a context where it is not available and the `No Overlay widget found` error is as a result of Flutter widgets requiring an Overlay, like Dialog, Drawer, SnackBar, etc., being used in a part of the widget tree where no Overlay is available(MaterialApp, CupertinoApp, or WidgetsApp is not an ancestor).

Try swapping the position of `Theme` and `MaterialApp.router` by doing either of the below:

```
return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 780),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: router,
        builder: (context, router) {
          return Theme(
            data: lightTheme,
            child: router!,
          );
        },
        title: 'FlyMedia',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
```

***OR***

```
return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 780),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp.router(
        routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
        routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
        builder: (context, router) {
          return Theme(
            data: lightTheme,
            child: router!,
          );
        },
        title: 'FlyMedia',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. For the router, I did router ?? getHome() It navigated and the overlay issue was fixed.